# built ExtJs 4.2, app doesn't run without old classes

Tags: extjs, build, sdk, cmd

I minified/built my app that uses ExtJS 4.2.0 (free version) using Sencha SDK Tools 2.0.0 beta3, and the app was built successfully. However, when I try deleting the old "app" folder containing my old classes, the app no longer works.

I also tried generating a new app using Sencha CMD 4.0.1.45 and then adding my classes, but the results are the same.

I am confused why this happens, because as I understood it, your old classes are not needed to deploy production app. In fact, the only javascript files you need to include in your "index.html" file are "ext.js" and "app-all.js".

I used Firebug and saw in the DOM that the app, along with my classes, are loaded.

I also noticed that "app-all.js" defines classes like this:

```
Ext.define("MyApp.view.MyClass"...
```

Is this really how it is supposed to behave? or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Okay, I got it. A .js file in my application calls Ext.require on itself, causing the app wiring go crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got it. A .js file in my application calls Ext.require on itself, causing the app wiring go crazy.